# How can I find the origin of a queued timer in an Angular unittest (karma/jasmine)

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine

So we've inherited a pretty convoluted framework from a previous team, and before I start refactoring I want to get all our unittests running again.

A problem I keep seeing is that about half our tests fail with a variation of:

`Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.`

I've tried just about everything from `async` with `whenStable`, to `fakeAsync` with `flush` and `discardPeriodicTasks` to get it to look past the timer, but to no avail. Even `tick(Infinity)` seems to do nothing. The timer is always there.

Is there any way to find out the origin of the timer when debugging?

Comment: The error seems to come from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/zone.js/lib/testing/fake-async.ts#L81). Maybe if you could place a breakpoint there, it would be easier to find what's wrong. Also, have you tried `resetFakeAsyncZone()` ?